# Go library: cannot find module providing package lib

Tags: go, packaging, go-modules

I am creating 3 separate go projects: `ace`, `aces-client` and a library shared by both projects `aceslib`. I am having trouble including the shared library according to the go-documentation (https://golang.org/doc/code.html#Library)

all go files in aceslib share the package-name `aceslib`. I am including the library in ace and aces-client with `import lib "aceslib"`. I can build the library with `go build` and it gets installed with `go install`, in the directory listing one can see that the file `go/pkg/windows_amd64/aceslib.a` gets created.

But when I try to build `ace` or `ace-client` go complains:

```
$ go build 
build ace: cannot load aceslib: cannot find module providing package aceslib
```

My go setup:

```
$ go version
go version go1.12.9 windows/amd64
$ go env
set GOARCH=amd64
set GOBIN=
set GOCACHE=C:\Users\Yulivee\AppData\Local\go-build
set GOEXE=.exe
set GOFLAGS=
set GOHOSTARCH=amd64
set GOHOSTOS=windows
set GOOS=windows
set GOPATH=C:\Users\Yulivee\go
set GOPROXY=
set GORACE=
set GOROOT=c:\go
set GOTMPDIR=
set GOTOOLDIR=c:\go\pkg\tool\windows_amd64
set GCCGO=gccgo
set CC=gcc
set CXX=g++
set CGO_ENABLED=1
set GOMOD=C:\Users\Yulivee\go\src\ace\go.mod
set CGO_CFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_CPPFLAGS=
set CGO_CXXFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_FFLAGS=-g -O2
set CGO_LDFLAGS=-g -O2
set PKG_CONFIG=pkg-config
set GOGCCFLAGS=-m64 -mthreads -fmessage-length=0 -fdebug-prefix-map=C:\Users\Yulivee\AppData\Local\Temp\go-build024649150=/tmp/go-build -gno-record-gcc-switches
```

Directory Structure:

```
.
├── bin
│   ├── ace-client.exe
│   └── ace.exe
├── pkg
│   ├── mod
│   │   ├── cache
│   │   └── golang.org
│   └── windows_amd64
│       ├── ace
│       ├── aceslib.a
│       └── golang.org
└── src
    ├── ace
    │   ├── README.md
    │   ├── go.mod
    │   ├── go.sum
    │   └── main.go
    ├── ace-client
    │   └── main.go
    ├── aceslib
    │   ├── README.md
    │   ├── crypto.go
    │   ├── go.mod
    │   └── utils.go
```

What am I missing?

---

Things I have tried, that did not help and lead to the same error:

```
$ go clean -i -x -cache -modcache
$ chmod 755 go/pkg/windows_amd64/aceslib.a
$ go get
build ace: cannot load aceslib: cannot find module providing package aceslib
$ rm -rf go/pkg/*
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The directory structure and package names are a bit off - it should be a URL to your project's repo, like every other import that isn't from the stdlib. If you have no repo and want to use local references you'll need to add a `replace` directive to `ace/go.mod` like so:

```
replace aceslib => ../aceslib
```

As documented [in the Modules docs](https://github.com/golang/go/wiki/Modules#can-i-work-entirely-outside-of-vcs-on-my-local-filesystem).

Answer (score 0):

IIRC, package names without directories are reserved for stdlib packages. So, you should first push the source tree down at least a level so you can access it by "dir/package".

Next, do you really want to treat these packages as separate modules? You have separate mod files under ace and aceslib packages. You may combine them under one module with a single go.mod at the project root and make life easier for yourself. That way you don't need redirects, etc.

You also have to include the modules with their directories:

```
import lib "dir/aceslib"
```

Comment: ace and aces-client share structs and some functionality, thats the reason for the seperation

Comment: Yes, but you don't need to make them separate modules. They can still be separate packages under a single module.